# Crons not working in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, cron, discount

I am using Magento 2.2.6 with a theme. [www.rbhomoeoshop.com](https://www.rbhomoeoshop.com) The store is using rule to offer x amount of discount on each and every product. There is no condition for discount.

after every 2 or 3 days the discount rule is removed by it self. I have to run a reindex command manually, using ssh.

One of my developer friend gave me a php file with reindex command and set a cron to run that php file twice in a day.

I am getting mail on execution of the cron file but the re-index command is not working. There is no error.

[image: current cron setting]

Requesting all to suggest a solution.

Comment: could you add `cron-man.php` code ?

Comment: Check database table `cron_schedule` see if your cron status is success. This will only show magento cronjobs. You don't need to run additional cron for reindex Magento cron should reindex this automatically

Comment: <?php
$cmd = "php -dmemory_limit=5G /home/rbhom2u9/public_html/bin/magento cache:clean";
exec($cmd, $a);
var_dump($a);
print("<hr/>");
$cmd = "php -dmemory_limit=5G /home/rbhom2u9/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush";
exec($cmd, $b);
var_dump($b);
print("<hr/>");
$cmd = "php -dmemory_limit=5G /home/rbhom2u9/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex";
exec($cmd, $c);
var_dump($c);

Comment: print("<hr/>");
$email_from = "support@rbhomoeoshop.com";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail("xxx@gmail.com", "Cron Man", "Cron Man executed.");

Answer (score 0):

Magento cronjob should run index automatically, there is no need to schedule through another file..

Please recheck following

**1. Check cron mode:**

> System -> Tools -> Index Management

Check if catalog rule indexes' modes are set on **"Update on Save"**

**2. Cron (Scheduled Tasks)**

> Store -> Configuration -> Advance -> System

In **Cron (Scheduled Tasks)** tab check if **Generate Schedules Every** value should be 1.

**3. Check database table** `cron_schedule` see if your cron status is success.

**4.** If it wont resolve **execute cron manually and check if it is working**:

```
php /home/rbhom2u9/public_html/update/cron.php
```

5. Check if **update in progress flag exists** in `var` directory
   if it exists, give read write permission to var directory and remove file `var/.update_in_progress.flag` and try to execute cron manually

Comment: Update on schedule is the setting.

Comment: settings in Store -> Configuration -> Advance -> System --- are as below. 
1,4,2,10,60,4320, yes

Comment: Did you execute you cron manually on shell through `php /home/rbhom2u9/public_html/update/cron.php` is it wokring?

Comment: just checked the DB... all crons are pending on single date which is 3 feb, 2019. There is no other date. now executing the command.

Comment: [2019-01-02 09:18:40] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
[2019-01-02 10:20:53] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
[2019-01-04 03:50:55] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
[2019-02-15 05:38:33] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []

Comment: Updated my answer, check point 5

Comment: no, there is no such file - .update_in_progress.flag

Comment: The problem is, that there are more connections to the database, than mysql allows.
The reason is most likely an inappropriate config for php/mysql. (e.g. more php-fpm worker than allowed mysql connections)

To allow more connections, the value for "max_connections" in the mysql configuration (Default path: /etc/my.cnf) file must be modified.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11924

Comment: I use shared hosting. I need to check with the hosting company.